# How could I pass a JavaScript function without directly saying its name?

Tags: javascript, string, function, reference

Say I have a hundred functions and a hundred HTML buttons and I want to assign them all to their click events.

I could name them like button1, button2, button3, ... and function1, function2, function3 ...

Then say:

```
let btsn = document.getElementsByClassName("mybuttons");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", "function" + i);
}
```

Of course this doesn't work because a string literal doesn't get translated into an actual reference to the function, it's just me stating its name randomly and gets forgotten.

But is there some way I could achieve this as though that were possible?

---

edit:

The exact functionality I was looking for can be done by putting the functions in an array.

```
let funcs = [
    function a() { ; }
    function b() { ; }
    function c() { ; }
    function d() { ; }
    function e() { ; }
]
let btsn = document.getElementsByClassName("mybuttons");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", funcs[i]);
}
```

Comment: For starters, it's `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName`.

Comment: You could potentially use `window['function' + i]` if the function is in the global scope, otherwise you would need to try it on the nested scope that the functions exist in.  Potientially sticking them on a name space object.  However, this use case seems like a code smell.

Comment: Thank you but yes I'd have noticed this in the actual application, I just typed it wrong when posing the question.

Comment: You should redesign so you don't need a different function for each button. Use the same function, it can get the button that was clicked from the `event` argument.

Comment: I could, but then I need to assign all the relations manually still, instead of just one command with a loop.

Comment: I realized what you can do is put all your functions in an array and reference them by position.

`for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) btns[i].addEventListener("click", funcs[i]);`